# Google AdWords API Negative Keywords Blocking Targeted Keywords

Tags: api, keyword, blocking, google-ads-api

I was wondering if there was API Connectivity for Negative Keywords blocking Targeted Keywords.

Basically, if you create a keyword such as 'free bananas,' and then a negative keyword such as 'free,' the negative keyword is causing the targeted keyword to be blocked.  AdWords displays this as a notification, and suggests deleting the negative keyword.

I was wondering if anyone knew if this data had API Connectivity.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out from a Google AdWords API Team member that this data is NOT currently exposed in the API.

Answer (score 0):

> If you do not have anything free then use the word 'free' as negative keyword.
>
> If you have something free, do not use the 'free' negative. Try to find out the exact search words contains 'free' from the Analytics. And then put the whole phrase as negative. You need to have the AdWords campaign connected to the analytics.
>
> Negative keywords can be added Campaign and adgroup level. You can use this opportunity.

Hope this helps. DO not hesitate to contact for further assistance.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thank you for the feedback, however my question wasn't in regards to usage strategies of keywords or negative keywords, that was simply an example.  My question was regarding the API, and if the API exposed the result set from when this collision in keywords occurs.